# Creating a datasource from fetching the data source

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Currently,I am storing database details in a property file and then creating an datasource using

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>${driverClassName}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>${url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>${username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${password}</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My Client asked us to place a config database and this DB will store all the i18keys and the main database values.

So I need to create one two datasources one is for Configs and other is the main database.

I can create the config data sources using the same. But How I can create an second datasource as all the database details are stored in config database.

can you pointers will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look into the Java-configuration for Spring. You can combine that with your current XML-configuration using `<context:component-scan base-package="..."/>`.

The general approach would be to configure the first datasource for configuration (like in your current setup) using XML. The XML should also refer to a 'configuration class'.

That is a special class, annotated with `@Configuration`, which gets the first datasource injected (or maybe some DAO), and then defines a method like so:

```
@Bean
public DataSource secondDataSource() {
    // Construct the second datasource using the configuration
    // retrieved from the first datasource.
    return new BasicDataSource();
}
```

Note that you might want to add a qualifier to either (or even both) datasources so you can distinguish between the two datasources when you want to have them injected into other beans using `@Inject`or `@Autowired`.